# Entity Framework Database query results in NULL values

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I am creating a WPF app using C#, Entity Framework and SQL Server 2008 R2. I am trying to fire the following query.

```sql
Select Convert(nvarchar(10),bk.BookingDate,103) as Date, Count(*) 
from Booking bk
where  
    Convert(date,bk.BookingDate) between '2014-10-01' and '2014-10-31'
    and bk.IsDeleted = 0
group by Convert(nvarchar(10),bk.BookingDate,103)
order by 1
```

This query works if directly fired on SQL Server prompt and fetches results.
However when I am trying using Entity Framework I am getting `NULL` value.

```
var values = context.Database
    .SqlQuery<KeyValuePair<string, int>>(query)
    .ToList<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
```

[image]

1. Is it because I am using a KeyValue pair in the method call?
2. Is there any alternative of doing this using Entity Framework?
3. Or should I use old style database connection and command to run this
   query?

Comment: why are you alternating using BookingDate as a string and date?  If it's stored as a date in your database, select it and compare it as a date

Comment: Just a hint in case you are not aware: EntityFramework works best with LinQ and NOT writing plain Text SQL-Queries.

Comment: @Kritner: in database its datetime. I want count by date. So need to erase the time part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because you're using the `KeyValuePair<>`, try creating a simple class like:

```
public class MyResult
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
}
```

And add `count(*) as TotalCount` to your query.  And use that as the generic type parameter for your `SqlQuery` call.  A key thing to remember is that EF will look for members on the result type with names that *match* the columns returned from the query.  So as an example, if your query returned a column called "total_count", you would need a property on your class also called "total_count" (with the underscore).

Comment: Its worth a try!!  Thanks :)